# How do I make one user see a different table with same name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Goal: When everybody else does SELECT * FROM mytable they see one version of the table.  But when a specific user does SELECT * FROM mytable they see another version of the table.

I think I'm like halfway there with creating a new role and putting the single user in it.  Then creating a copy of the default table with SELECT * INTO newrole.mytable FROM dbo.mytable.  But when the user does SELECT * FROM mytable they still see the dbo.mytable.  How do I get them to default to the newrole.mytable?  I still need them to see all the other dbo tables just not this one.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Sounds like you're going to create a maintenance nightmare. Consider creating separate databases, tables or adding a field (e.g., IsAdminUser) and include this in a WHERE clause.

Comment: What in the world are you doing this for?

Comment: @Spencer Ruport, @Bob Kaufman.  I can't answer for the original poster but my first thought was for security purposes.  Some fields of a table require a higher security clearance for example.  An old friend discussed some research on this idea with me years ago but I don't know what modern databases do to protected more sensitive fields.

Comment: The table contains security settings for the application.  When accessed via the desktop application, the customer wants one security setting.  When accessed via the web application, they want a different security setting.  I can't alter the table structure or the code behind the apps.

Comment: Also I got it working as above in sql server 2000, I just had to stop and restart sql server for the changes to take effect.  I was tearing my hair out wondering why I could still see dbo.mytable after I had denied permissions on it.  I don't remember ever having to restart it for permission or role changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new schema, and a duplicate table (or view onto dbo.table if that's what you want) in it - eg., otheruser.table. Then, set the user's login to default to that schema:

```
USE atest
GO

CREATE ROLE [arole]
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [aschema] AUTHORIZATION [arole]
GO

CREATE USER [auser] FOR LOGIN [modify_user] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = aschema
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'arole', 'auser'
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.atable ( col1 int )
GO

CREATE TABLE aschema.atable (col2 varchar(10))
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.atable( col1 ) VALUES( 1 )
GO

INSERT INTO aschema.atable( col2 ) VALUES( 'One' )
GO

PRINT 'dbo'
SELECT * FROM atable
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'auser'
GO

PRINT 'aschema'
SELECT * FROM atable
GO

REVERT
GO
```

Comment: are schemas in sql server 2000?  The actual implementation will be 2005 but I have 2000 on my test instance.

Comment: How would you handle mixed roles if you use schemas?

Comment: This approach is also poor if MyTable in either schema is identical.

Comment: @Will Rickards - Yes, schemas are in SQL 2000 - though some of the specific T-SQL syntax changes.

Comment: @rexem - You assign a *user* a default schema - you set the role as owner of the schema (so that you can drop a user without dropping the schema and it's associated objects). Frankly, the role isn't necessary for this example.

Comment: @rexem - Also, MyTable being identical doesn't really make a difference. It'd be confusing, but really the intent of the OP is to "lie" to the user - which equals confusion in most cases. To be fair though, schemas are a lesser known MSSQL feature - and I wouldn't suggest their use in most cases.

Comment: I haven't tested the schema thing, I got it working without schemas but I'll go ahead and accept this answer as it is probably the correct way to do it.  This is just a proof of concept at this stage anyway.

Comment: Proof of concept for a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this may help but you may be able to make a view of a different table with the same name, here is an excerpt from http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_view.asp:

In SQL, a view is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement.

A view contains rows and columns, just like a real table. The fields in a view are fields from one or more real tables in the database.

You can add SQL functions, WHERE, and JOIN statements to a view and present the data as if the data were coming from one single table.

Comment: You can't make a view with the same name as an existing table in the same schema.  If you try, you'll get error Msg 2714 ("object with that name already exists").

Comment: Unless you put that view into a different schema, then you can't create a view with the same name as a table. Furthermore, you can't direct a specific user to a view instead of a table. This, frankly, doesn't answer the question at all - and is incorrect as well.

Answer (score 1):

I use Postgres primarily, so YMMV, but in postgres you need to

1) Create the new schema, preferably owned by the new role, and put the table in it
2) Set the search_path variable to include that schema BEFORE the other one.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very bad idea. I'm not sure why people try all these crazy methods to improve security but it's just plain counter productive.

Ultimately every security system comes down to some line like the following `if(User.HasAccessTo(object))`. In fact, if you've designed a well thought out security system that's almost exactly how it should work. The more disjointed your authentication checks, the more likely you'll make a mistake. If only some users have access to certain record information you should add a flag to those records and verify access based on that.